# separate (binary) implementation of ulimit command?

Tags: linux, limits, ulimit

Is there a source code for **/usr/bin/ulimit**? I need to see a user's complete list of `rlimit`'s without him being in a shell.

In this case, we have problems running memory-intensive programs from the web server (user wwwrun, usually having `/bin/false` as login shell in `/etc/passwd`), and we suspect some system-imposed limits are blocking it from completing these programs.

In former times, there has been a /usr/bin/ulimit binary, but these seem to be gone.

So what I'm looking for is a C implementation of the ulimit command (nowadays usually being only available as (ba)sh built-in). It doesn't need to have any "setrlimit" capabilities - just printing all limits would be sufficient. We'd then set this command as wwwrun's login shell and a "su - wwwrun" would show all rlimits this user has.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be any `/usr/bin/ulimit` (or `/usr/bin/cd`) executable, because the [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall operate on the *current* shell process (changing a property of the current process which will by default be inherited by further child processes, see [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)). So `ulimit`, like `cd` (which invokes the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall), has to be a shell builtin

From inside your *C* program just call the `setrlimit` syscall. Don't forget to test for failure (and on failure display `errno` perhaps using `perror`  or `strerror`). To query the current limits, use [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) or read -within your program- sequentially the `/proc/self/limits` pseudo-file (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more, or `/proc/1234/limits` for process of pid 1234).

```
FILE* f = fopen("/proc/self/limits", "r");
if (f) {
   char linbuf[128];
   do { 
     memset (linbuf, 0, sizeof(linbuf));
     fgets (linbuf, sizeof(linbuf), f);
     fputs(linbuf, stderr);
   } while (!feof(f));
   fclose (f);
   fflush(NULL);
} else perror("/proc/self/limits");
```

I also recommend reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html). See also [Linux PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) and configuration files like `/etc/security/limits.conf` and under `/etc/pam.d/`

Comment: Thanks Basile - that's the theory and I was aware of that...

As said, I don't want to do any "setrlimit", I just need to _know_ what `rlimit`s are **in effect** at the time of eg. "su - wwwrun".

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hints - I've set a simple text file `cat-limits` as login shell for wwwrun, simply containing one line with

```
#!/bin/cat /proc/self/limits
```

and that gave me what I want.

Cheers